# Azure Pipelines job stuck building iOS version of React Native app

Tags: ios, azure, react-native, fastlane

I'm trying to build an iOS version of a React Native app using Azure Pipelines. I'm running the build using fastlane's action `build_ios_app`.

It works on my local machine perfectly fine, but it gets stuck on Azure with the following output:

```
[08:32:21]: ‌▸‌ ‌Compiling‌ LaunchScreen.xib‌
[08:32:25]: ‌▸‌ ‌Processing‌ Info.plist‌
[08:32:25]: ‌▸‌ ‌Running script‌: Bundle React Native code and images
‌[08:32:32]: ▸ ‌the transform cache was reset.‌
```

This is usually the step at which the packager is opened in a new terminal window.

On my local machine the output looks a little bit different at this step:

```
[11:38:15]: ▸ Processing Info.plist
[11:38:15]: ▸ Running script 'Bundle React Native code and images'
[11:38:15]: ▸ Touching Demo.app (in target: Demo)
[11:38:16]: ▸ Archive Succeeded
```

There is no `‌the transform cache was reset.‌` which indicates node is running out of memory on the Azure at some point?

- Bundling the app manually (via `react-native bundle ...`) works fine though.

**Update:** Increasing the memory available for nodejs tasks (setting `--max-old-space-size=8096` in the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable) makes the job fail (at least) with the following error message:

```
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6108820Z error: File /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-algdypqdcfcqirejrjxxgvqsmfdv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Demo/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Demo.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with[0m

2019-07-29T09:58:04.6109130Z 
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6109180Z 
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6109640Z [33m▸[0m [39;1mGenerating 'Demo.app.dSYM'[0m
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6109740Z ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6109810Z 
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6109850Z 
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6109930Z The following build commands failed:
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6111020Z PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-algdypqdcfcqirejrjxxgvqsmfdv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Demo/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Demo.build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh
2019-07-29T09:58:04.6111240Z (1 failure)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on my local machine, the solution was to **update to the latest version of node js**.

I guess your CI environment should be self contained, so version conflicts should not be a problem. But you maybe updated fastlane to a version incompatible with the node on your Azure server without realizing.